# Jest encountered an unexpected token React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

This is screenshot of error: [image: error in tests]

I have 2 tests, the first one is working alright: sum.js :

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  module.exports = sum;
```

sum.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 2 + 5 to equal 7', () => {
  expect(sum(2, 5)).toBe(7);
});
```

it works okay, prints message in console.

the second one (I dont sure) is set by default by create-react-app

App.test.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from './routes';
import Alerts from './app/components/alerts';
import Navbar from '../src/app/navbar/navbar'
import Auth from './app/settings/auth';
import Register from './app/entities/user/modify-modal';
import './index.scss';

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
                <>
                    <Auth></Auth>
                    <Navbar></Navbar>
                    <Alerts></Alerts>
                    <Register/>
                    <div className={"content-root"}>
                        <Routes/>
                    </div>
                </>
            </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "x5_r_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.1",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "jest-cli": "^24.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^14.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^3.2.4",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
    "react-debounce-input": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "react-select": "^2.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^7.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "test": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0"
  }
}
```

package-lock.json is 20000 rows of code, so I dont know, what part of it is needed for explanation of my problem, all guides that I've read about this problem were useless for me, so I am asking here.

Comment: `create-react-app` sets up your test environment for you, including `babel` which is required to test code using JSX.  Unless you are ejecting from `create-react-app`, just let it take care of `Jest` configuration and launch.  (It looks like you installed the latest version of `Jest` and modified your `test` script in `package.json`...don't do that unless you are going to stop using `create-react-app`).

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors yes, thank you, I made git stash and returned to the original settings of create-react-app and everything become fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the app was bootstrapped with `create-react-app`, but then the latest version of `Jest` was also installed and the `npm test` script within `package.json` was changed to launch `jest` directly.

The test failed since `Jest` was not configured to transpile the JSX syntax.

---

Tests that use syntax like JSX have to be transpiled before they can be run by `Jest`.

`create-react-app` includes `react-scripts` which handles all of that configuration automatically.

---

If an app is bootstrapped with `create-react-app` then `Jest` does not need to be installed and configured manually.

---

If an app is not bootstrapped with `create-react-app`, or if the app is ejected from `create-react-app`, then `Jest` needs to be installed and configured to transpile the test code.

Comment: Hi @Brain Adams, 
I have exact same error , so should I uninstall Jest and then how do I configure Jest manually, could you please share steps /information please . I am at a very beginner level with REACT and JEST

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also your statement:  "If an app is bootstrapped with create-react-app then Jest does not need to be installed and configured manually." --> Does this means if the app uses Bootstrap library then Jest is not needed to be installed and need to be configured manually? could you please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Auo If you created your app with `create-react-app` (ie, "boostrapped" it with `create-react-app) and haven't ejected it then `Jest` is already included and you *should not* add it as a dev dependency.  The `package.json` includes a `jest` config section and you can configure how `Jest` runs in that section.

Comment: Thank you Brian I have now understood and fixed my issue, you are very helpful.